# How to redirect a user after submit of a form in kohana 3.3

Tags: php, kohana-3.3

I want to redirect a user after they submit their messages to a database. The submit query executes but the redirect request fails and gives an error message "ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Request::instance()" I don't know what is going on. Am using Kohana 3.3.3. Here is my controller to add the message:

```
public function action_add()
        {
            $messages = new Model_Message;
            $user_id = $this->request->param('id');
            $this->template->content = View::factory('profile/message_form');
            if (isset($_POST['content']))
            {
                $messages->add($user_id, (string) $_POST['content']);
                $redirect = URL::site("messages/get_messages/$user_id");
                Request::instance()->redirect($redirect);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the following:

```
$this->redirect($redirect, 302);
```

302 for temporary redirect, 301 for permanent.

Comment: You're welcome. The way you tried did used to work in v3.2 I think, but they changed it in v3.3.